# Jenkins DSL, passed string doesnt much Enum => `No enum constant'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, enums

Hey I'm migrating jenkins to use DSL with groovy. When writing in DSL the config for a job one part needed some plugin and its docs show this method

```sh
mavenMetadataParameterDefinition {
...
  name(String value)
  description(String value)
...
  maxVersions(String value)
  sortOrder(String value)
...
}
```

for reference this is how it looks in Jenkins made manually [image]

So now I try to migrate it to DSL and generate it with the method above but it throws

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant eu.markov.jenkins.plugin.mvnmeta.MavenMetadataParameterDefinition.SortOrder.Descending
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
```

any thoughts how you pass Enum value in jenkins via dsl? - plugins docs say it has to be a string, but I tried writing all in caps `DESCENDING`, from small `descending`, big letter `Descending` - nth works same error

---

EDIT: I found the GitHub of the plugin, now looking for where the enum is defined https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-metadata-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/eu/markov/jenkins/plugin/mvnmeta/MavenMetadataParameterDefinition/config.jelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the value had to be `DESC` in plugins code i see

```sh
          <sortOrder>DESC</sortOrder>
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-metadata-plugin/blob/master/src/dev/assets/work/jobs/test-freestyle/config.xml#L19